# F# reduce function on List of Tuples

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0

This simple piece of code is stumping me

So this works

```
> let l = [1; 2; 3; 4];;
val l : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4]
> List.reduce(fun accm i -> accm + i) l;;
val it : int = 10
```

But this doesn't (even though the logic is exactly the same)

```
> let l = [("a", 1); ("b", 2); ("c", 3); ("d", 4)];;                         
val l : (string * int) list = [("a", 1); ("b", 2); ("c", 3); ("d", 4)]       

> List.reduce(fun accm tup -> accm + (snd tup)) l;;                          
List.reduce(fun accm tup -> accm + (snd tup)) l;;        

>stdin(46,47): error FS0001: The type 'int' does not match the type 'string * int'
```

Why do I get this error because the code is simple. iterate through the list take the tuple and pass it to the reduce function along with the value of the accumulator.

inside the function take the second value from the tuple and add it to the accumulator.

I know there may be many other ways of getting what I want ... but I want to know why the code above does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reduce`'s arguments should both have the same type as each other and the elements of the list (a tuple type in this case), but you're trying to add one to the second half of the other.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide an initial value.  If there's no initial value then `reduce` assumes the first value in the `List` is the initial value, which is a tuple.  Hence the error you're getting.

Comment: But reduce doesn't take a seed value (fold does). I looked the documentation here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370239.aspx

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch : I think "use `fold` instead of `reduce`" was indeed the underlying answer here.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are trying to do is `List.sumBy snd`.

`reduce` assumes that the accumulator is of the same type as a list item, which isn't the assumption the reducer function in the question is making.